# regex - find specific text between 2 specified boundary

Tags: regex, recursion

I'm trying to develop a regex that will detect recursive template calls in an xsl style sheet.

So far, it has not been really successful.

In the following code, I need to detect that template B is called recursively:

```
<xsl:template name="A"> 
     blah blha ?!@#?%$#^%?*?&(({}:"><;'[]\/.,./'
    <xsl:call-template name="B">  
    blah blah      
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template name="B"> 
   blah blha 
    <xsl:call-template name="B">                
    blah blah  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="C"> 
     blah blha 
    <xsl:call-template name="B">  
    blah blah  
</xsl:template>
```

In this specific case, the reg ex is ok.

In the case I remove the 2nd call to B, the regex matches the last call to B. That shouldn't happen.

```
(<xsl:template name=\"(?<templateName>\w+)\">.*?(?<=<xsl:call-template name=\"\k<templateName>\">).*?</xsl:template>)+
```

I'm no regex guru. Any help is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use regex to solve this.

Comment: "Regular expression" and "recursive" in the same sentence is a good sign that you're going to have trouble. Languages that require "nesting" are not regular, meaning you can't match them precisely with regular expressions. Some regex implementations let you do some non-regular things (eg: backreferences), but in general if what you're trying to match isn't a regular language, I wouldn't use a regular expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reiterating the obvious point: *Don't try parsing XML or other non-regular languages with regular expressions. Please.*

Use an XML parser and take a look at the resulting tree. You can create a digraph of the template calls and look for cycles in that. Should be a much more robust solution than trying to hack it together with regular expressions. That way you can also detect that template A might call template B which calls template C and which calls template A again. Such kinds of recursion would be invisible to your current approach (if it could be persuaded to work).

Comment: I agree, regex are not the perfect tool for that. 
But, I'm doing a little tool that will run once, maybe twice. I want to create something fast, can I can live with the fact that some calls like you describe won't be detected. I don't want to be involved in that project for long.
Can you suggest me an xml parser tool that you think would fit?

If it helps: I was planning on running this regex on multiple files with a script in powershell or iron python. 

thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Well, nearly every language has facilities for dealing with XML and simply walking the nodes probably doesn't require much effort. But I don't do this usually and thus am not really proficient in dealing with XML.

Comment: @Jean-Francois: PowerShell has extremely powerful XML support built in. See http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/30/chapter-14-xml.aspx